# Grouping coordinates which are close to each other

Tags: matlab, coordinates, unique, grouping

On the figure below is a plot of some (x,y) coordinates. As can be seen, the data is roughly divided into some "groups" of x-coordinates close to each other. It can also be seen that the distance between consecutive groups is varying.

I would like to get the indices for each "group" of x-coordinates, which I can then use to 'select' the associated y-coordinates.

So far I've tried:

```
[uniqueValues, ~, uniqueIdx] = uniquetol(x_coordinates,tol);
indices_group1 = find(uniqueIdx == 1);
x_group1 = x_coordinates(indicesGroup1);
y_group1 = y_coordinates(indicesGroup1);
```

which somewhat does what I want; but it doesn't work well due to the varying distance between the groups.
Any ideas on how to approach this?

[image]

Comment: I dont understand how the varying distance has an effect in this code. Can you explain that please?

Comment: @AnderBiguri perhaps OP couldn't find a `tol` that works well...?

Comment: @Dev-iL right, that makes sense. I don't know how to automatically shoose it, but my guess is that `tol=0.005` will do the job.

Comment: I played around with different values of tol, but couldnt find one that worked well for the whole range of data.

Comment: @jsjq for the data you show, `0.005` should work.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a clustering algorithm such as [DBScan](http://yarpiz.com/255/ypml110-dbscan-clustering). This should classify each 'line' of points as an individual cluster, then you can get the y-coordinates for every cluster.